# How to show customized activity for custom post types in buddypress activity loop?

Tags: custom-post-types, buddypress

I'm building a city portal/ social business directory with buddypress and wordpress. All business listings are stored as a custom post type called 'business'. I'm using the following code to show the activity related to business listings in the activity stream

```
function bbg_record_my_custom_post_type_comments( $post_types ) {
      $post_types[] = 'business';
      return $post_types;
  }
add_filter( 'bp_blogs_record_comment_post_types', 'bbg_record_my_custom_post_type_comments' );
```

this is the result https://i.stack.imgur.com/Poaay.png

Right now it says

> user commented on the post 'postname'

While I need it to say

> user wrote a review on 'postname'

for the business post type, and

> user commented on 'postname'

for other post types.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter on the action before it is saved by using add_filter on 
'bp_blogs_activity_new_comment_action' as shown in 
bp-blogs-functions.php -> bp_blogs_record_comment()

Or you can filter before the action is displayed by using add_filter on 
'bp_get_activity_action'

Probably better to do the former because you can easily check post->post_type to see if it is 'business'.

This shows how to adjust the activity action for the creation of a CPT:
http://buddypress.org/community/groups/how-to-and-troubleshooting/forum/topic/display-custom-post-types-in-activity-feed/
You should be able to adjust that to handle comments.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I read the function in bp-blogs-functions.php and picked up the things I needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @shanebp for the answer. I'm posting my complete function as the answer so it can help others too(wasn't sure if I was to add it to the question itself)

```
function jw_record_my_custom_comments_strings($activity_action, $comment_id, $is_approved = true ) {
        global $bp;
        $recorded_comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
        // Get blog and post data
        $blog_id                = get_current_blog_id();
        $recorded_comment->post = get_post( $recorded_comment->comment_post_ID );

        if ( in_array( $recorded_comment->post->post_type, apply_filters( 'bp_blogs_record_comment_post_types', array( 'business' ) ) ) )
            $activity_action = sprintf( __( '%1$s wrote a review on, %2$s', 'buddypress' ), bp_core_get_userlink( $user_id ), '<a href="' . $post_permalink . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $recorded_comment->post->post_title ) . '</a>' );


        return $activity_action;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
     * Replaces activity action with dynamic activity action 
     * @uses    bp_get_activity_action() filter
 */ 

function  custom_activity_action($action) { 

    $user_id =  bp_get_activity_user_id();
    $user_link = bp_core_get_userlink( $user_id );
    $activity_timestamp = bp_insert_activity_meta();

    if ($activity_type=='YOUR ACTIVITY TYPE HERE i.e activity_update'){

       $action = sprintf( __( '%s posted a snippet %2$s', 'buddypress' ), $user_link, $activity_timestamp  );

       return $action;
   }

   return $action ; 

}
add_filter('bp_get_activity_action', 'custom_activity_action');
```